# UA code is not there in site but analytics is set

Tags: google, google-analytics

Came through one site.There is no UA code or ga.js in the source code of site.
But the analytics account is set and showing visits in real time. How is it possible to hide UA code or analytics code.

Comment: Yes that is possible to hide your UA/GA code from source. It is depends on programming technology which you are using for your site. For diff. platform there is diff. techniques to hide it.

Comment: A code is not visible can have one more reason that The version of tracking code that they are using is almost a year out of date.

Comment: Ga.js is an old script that isnt used anymore for Universal Analytics. You should search for analytics.js now (unless you are positive you are using ye olde script).

Comment: Also possible that they're using Google Tag Manager, which dynamically ads the Analytics code via Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of possible answers to your question, sorted by most probable scenario in my opinion:

1.The tracking code is added in an external `.js` file which is requested when the html file is downloaded.
 2.The tracking code is added in a different domain and the `cookieDomain` field of the tracker is set to `none`.
 3.The Google Analytics tracking code (both versions) might be obfuscated as well. Take a look at the following [tool](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/).